# PowerShell to find if today is in between two other days

Tags: powershell, datetime

Given a start day and time (Friday 5PM) and an end day and time (Monday 5AM), how would one use PowerShell to find out if today was between the two?  I'm at a complete loss.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming local timestamps:

If you define this function:

```
function Test-TimeWindow {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] [DateTime] $TimeStamp,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] [DayOfWeek] $FromDay,
    [timespan] $FromTime = '00:00',
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] [DayOfWeek] $ToDay,
    [timespan] $ToTime = '00:00' 
  )

  $interveningFullDays = [int] $ToDay + (0, 7)[[int] $FromDay -gt [int] $ToDay] - $FromDay - 1
  [dayofweek[]] $interveningFullDoWs = 
    if ($interveningFullDays -gt 0) {
      foreach ($i in 1..$interveningFullDays) {
        ([int] $FromDay + $i) % 7
      }
    }
  
  $TimeStamp.DayOfWeek -in $interveningFullDoWs -or
    ($TimeStamp.DayOfWeek -eq $FromDay -and $TimeStamp.TimeOfDay -ge $FromTime) -or 
    ($TimeStamp.DayOfWeek -eq $ToDay -and $TimeStamp.TimeOfDay -le $ToTime)

}
```

You can call it as follows:

```sh
# Outputs $true if the current point in time falls inside the specified window.
# Note: 
#  * '17:00' is the 24-hour-clock representation of 5 PM
#     Both times must be represented in this format.
#  * Day-of-week names can be abbreviated, as long as the abbrevation
#    is unambiguous.
Test-TimeWindow (Get-Date) Fri 17:00 Mon 05:00
```

Comment: I like it! Only potential issue is this assumes the target Fri-Mon is in the current week.

Comment: Very elegant and answers my literal question.  The problem is as @DougMaurer suggests.  This is part of a change window creation routine where the user supplies the start and stop dates.  Friday through Monday may not always be selected.

Comment: Thanks, @DougMaurer, but this isn't about a particular week at all - it applies to _any_ week.

Comment: @mklement0 I see, my mistake. This is just saying "am I a date between any friday 5pm and sunday at 5am"

Comment: Glad to hear it, @StevieJ - getting this to work as intended (I hope) was trickier than anticipated.

Answer (score 2):

If you have/can calculate the appropriate dates then you can test if it is less than and greater than.

```
$today = Get-Date

$monday = Get-Date '03-29-2021 07:00'

$friday = Get-Date '03-26-2021 17:00'

$today -le $monday -and $today -ge $friday  # returns false for today 03-24-2021
```

Test for actual date/time within the criteria

```
$testday = Get-Date '03-28-2021 19:33'

$testday -lt $monday -and $testday -gt $friday # returns true
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I won't know the actual dates.  Its part of a weekly change window.  I want to ask the user what day they want to pick for start and stop.  I should have been more specific in the question.

Comment: The solution would still apply.  You'll prompt or otherwise take input from the user.  Store that in a variable and from there it should track with Doug's answer.

Comment: @steven thank you, beat me to it. Stevie J, perhaps show how the date strings will look once captured.

Comment: Incidentally, in cases of date ranges, I like to consider `-le` & `-ge`.  In this case it would cover the edge case that the user specifies a time exactly at the open or close of the window.

Answer (score 0):

```
function IsTodayInbetween($startDay, $startTime, $endDay, $endTime) {
    $date = Get-Date 
    $time = (Get-Date).TimeOfDay;
    $startTimeFormatted = [datetime]::ParseExact($startTime, "h tt", $null).TimeOfDay;
    $endTimeFormatted = [datetime]::ParseExact($endTime, "h tt", $null).TimeOfDay;

    $daysToStart = 0;
    if ($date.AddDays($daysToStart).DayOfWeek -ne $startDay) {
        do { $daysToStart++; } while ($date.AddDays($daysToStart).DayOfWeek -ne $startDay);
    }
    $daysToEnd = 0
    if ($date.AddDays($daysToEnd).DayOfWeek -ne $endDay) {
        do { $daysToEnd++; } while ($date.AddDays($daysToEnd).DayOfWeek -ne $endDay)
    }

    if ($daysToEnd -gt $daysToStart -And $daysToStart -ne 0) { return $false }
    if (($daysToStart -eq 0 -And $time -lt $startTimeFormatted)) { 
        return $false; 
    }
    if (($daysToEnd -eq 0 -And $time -gt $endTimeFormatted))
    {
        return $false;
    }
    return $true;
    
    
}


write-host "Is Todays date inbetween ? $((IsTodayInbetween -startDay 'Monday' -startTime '5 AM' -endDay 'Friday' -endTime '5 PM'))";
write-host "Is Todays date inbetween ? $((IsTodayInbetween -startDay 'Thursday' -startTime '5 AM' -endDay 'Thursday' -endTime '5 PM'))";
write-host "Is Todays date inbetween ? $((IsTodayInbetween -startDay 'Monday' -startTime '5 AM' -endDay 'Friday' -endTime '5 PM'))";
write-host "Is Todays date inbetween ? $((IsTodayInbetween -startDay 'Friday' -startTime '5 AM' -endDay 'Monday' -endTime '5 PM'))";
write-host "Is Todays date inbetween ? $((IsTodayInbetween -startDay 'Saturday' -startTime '5 AM' -endDay 'Sunday' -endTime '5 PM'))";
write-host "Is Todays date inbetween ? $((IsTodayInbetween -startDay 'Thursday' -startTime '2 PM' -endDay 'Monday' -endTime '5 PM'))";
write-host "Is Todays date inbetween ? $((IsTodayInbetween -startDay 'Saturday' -startTime '5 AM' -endDay 'Friday' -endTime '5 PM'))";
```

Comment: IsTodayInbetween -startDay 'Monday' -startTime '5 AM' -endDay 'Friday' -endTime '5 PM'

Comment: Just thought I'd add the literal function call. I also assumed, you were dealing with a string of 5 am and not a datetime value.

Comment: Included some run throughs to output to the console.